# WxPython - Mouse Click Not getting recognised on the GUI

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to python. I am trying to gather links from youtube based on search string. Assumption is the link I want will be the first result on my search results.
Problem I am facing is mouse clicks are not recognised on the gui. It just moves to the x,y cordinates but I cannot see that it is getting clicked. Please help me to understand why this clicks are not recognized.

Below is the code:  I created a GUI in wxpython, and I am trying to click on search bar of youtube, then paste the search string, then click on search take the link address from the first result. This below code is sample code.  In my real code search string will be passed from excel sheet.

```
   import win32api, win32con
   import win32com.client as win32
   from win32com.client import Dispatch, Constants
   import os
   import time
   import win32clipboard
   import wx
   import wx.html2
   import sys




   x_pad = 0
   y_pad = 0


   def leftClick():
       wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN
       time.sleep(.1)
       wx.EVT_LEFT_UP
       print "Click."          #completely optional. But nice for debugging purposes.

   def rightClick():
       wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN
       time.sleep(.1)
       wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP
       print "Right Click."     #completely optional. But nice for debugging purposes.


   def mousePos(cord):
       win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1]))

   class URL(wx.Frame):

       def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
           super(URL, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 

           self.InitUI()




       def InitUI(self):   
           pnl = wx.Panel(self)
           sbtn = wx.Button(pnl, label='Start', pos=(850, 560))
           cbtn = wx.Button(pnl, label='Close', pos=(850, 610))
           stdot = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, pos =(400,580),size=(400,80), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
           sys.stdout = stdot
           sys.stderr = stdot

           sbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)
           cbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)



           brwser = wx.html2.WebView.New(pnl, size = (1280,550), pos = (0,0), url =("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sarabhai+vs+sarabhai+episode+25&sm=3"))        


           self.SetSize((1280, 720))
           self.SetTitle('YouTube URL Grab')
           self.SetPosition((0,0))
           self.Show(True)


       def OnStart(self,e):
           win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
           win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
           win32clipboard.SetClipboardText("Sarabhai vs Sarabhai episode 31") #Sample string for search
           win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
           mousePos((252, 53))
           leftClick()
           leftClick()
           leftClick()
           rightClick()
           time.sleep(5)
           mousePos((280, 144))
           leftClick()
           time.sleep(5)
           mousePos((755, 53))
           leftClick()
           time.sleep(7)
           mousePos((467, 140))
           rightClick()
           time.sleep(5)
           mousePos((514, 321))
           leftClick()


       def OnClose(self, e):

           self.Close(True) 


   def main():

       ex = wx.App()
       URL(None)
       ex.MainLoop()    


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The names `wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN` and `wx.EVT_LEFT_UP` are actually just numbers for the event identifies that you need to bind to they **do not cause the events to happen**!  Look at the examples in the docs and demos package.

The basic process is:

During frame intitialisation bind handlers to the events you need to handle, these should be of type `fn(self, evt)` and by convention are named `onNameOfEvent` e.g. `def onLeftBtnDown(self, evt)` these contain the events that you need to react to and the evt parameter gives you an event object the members of which depend on the event type.  The event binding uses the format `self.Bind(wx.EVT_NAME_OF_EVENT, onNameOfEvent)` and is normally in the windows `__init__` method, *(this is what the vast majority of GUI code does, including non wx GUIs)*.

If, (much more rarely), you need to generate events ***from your code*** rather than just reacting to the events ***you still need to do the above*** then where you need to create the event by declaring the appropriate type of event object, e.g. wx.CommandEvent, *(note that you can create your own event types)*, populating with the required values and then use 'wx.PostEvent' to add it to the event queue for the window or control that it applies to.  Sometime later, when it gets to the top of the queue, your event handler will be called with this event.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did go through the wxpython docs but Unfortunately I am not getting how I should proceed further. Let me know if something I am missing basic here.

Comment: Expanded explanation added @just10minutes - hope it helps.